# 5-level inverter using H-bridge with MOSFETs

Tags: inverter, h-bridge, series

I want to make a 5-level inverter using an H-bridge. I have made an H-bridge using MOSFETs and it works. My problem comes when adding the output of these two H-bridges to get 5 voltage levels. I am adding the outputs like we join two batteries in series but for some reason it is not working with my circuit. Can anyone help me with this?

[image: Circuit in Proteus]

Comment: In effect you are connecting two parallel batteries but in antiphase and nothing good is going to happen from that.

Comment: Do you have a reference where two H bridges can be connected to give a 5-level inverter?

Comment: Do more reading Neutral Point Clamped 

(NPC), Cascaded H-Bridge (CHB), Flying Capacitor 

Converters (FCC), and Modular Multilevel Converters 

(MMC)

Comment: Have you mastered the 2 level converter yet? https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/read/18800114/mosfet-igbt-drivers-theory-and-applications-educypedia-site Do not skip ahead until you do.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply connect common-supply H-bridges in series.  There is a common-mode return path through the supplies which shorts them out.

Isolated supplies (and gate drives, by extension) are mandatory.

Answer (score -1):

In case someone comes in future and sees it.
You need to give negative voltage to gate of P-MOSFET instead of ground to turn it ON. Doing that will make it work.